# javascript hide() and show() not hiding all content as it's supposed to

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, hide

I have the following code which is supposed to first change the text if a checkbox is checked (which works fine) and second, SHOW a div with dropdown boxes. If the checkbox is unchecked then it should HIDE the div again.

The problem is that the div contains a javascript generated dropdown box which allows one to add/remove fields based on their need.

If you test it, you'll notice that when you check the checkbox and then click on "Add country", then uncheck the checkbox again, the "Add country" disappears but the dropdowns generated don't disappear.

Is there any way to also hide the dropdowns again if the checkbox is unchecked again?

Here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/shannont/GpNdS/1/

Comment: Your HTML markup is seriously invalid.  A `<table>` element cannot have a `<div>` directly beneath it like that.

Comment: If you use JQuery, use it everywhere. Creating your new options, I even saw that `document.getElementById("tblCountryCurrency")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is invalid. You have

```
<table>
   <div>
   ...
</table>
```

A `<table>` cell can directly contain tr/tbody/thead tags only. A bare div inside a table will "leak" out of the table.

You also have two `</table>` closing tags below, but have only one `<table>` tag open.

Fix your html first. Clean it up so it's more legible - don't stuff script blocks into the middle of markup. It's confusing and hard to read.

Comment: Yes, please take your script blocks out of your code and move them into the head. Simple things like this will make your development life a lot easier!

Comment: Wow, I was really dumb. Sorry about that, it works perfectly now! I guess I was just trying too hard :)

Answer (score 1):

Your browser is auto-correcting your syntactically invalid html. You can't put divs and images inside a table. You need to put in rows and cells first. The page then breaks because the javascript isn't targeting what you think it is targeting.

```
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="tblCountryCurrency">
       <div id="detailedID" style="display: none;">
           <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" title="Add Row" border="0" onclick="addRowToCountryPrice('',''); return false;">
       <a href="" onclick="addRowToCountryPrice('',''); return false;">Add a Country</a>
       <input type="hidden" name="TotalLinesCountry" id="TotalLinesCountry">
```

Example Fix:

```
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="tblCountryCurrency">
    <tr>
       <td><div id="detailedID" style="display: none;"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

You probably don't want to use a table here at all though. So I would recommend pulling that out and replacing it with a div. Then your code will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Well even if it's a mess, just put your

```
<div id="detailedID" style="display: none;">
```

Before the table.